# vuetify too much gap from the App bar - How to reduce

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In my vue.js/vuetify app the gap between App bar and following contents is too much.

How can I minimize it?

Below is the screenshot

all help highly appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Would need to see some actual code/HTML to be sure, but you might have an extra `v-container` in there and/or a `fill-height` attribute that you don't need.

Comment: look at the documentation here https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the start of the SET UP Time table DIV OR V-layout or the tag from which it starts add this example code (**class="ma-0 pa-0"**)

```
<v-layout>
  <v-container class="ma-0 pa-0">
  </v-container>
</v-layout>
```

Comment: This seems to have reduced the gap significantly. I have added negative margin n12